# On the two words, several pronunciations, and many spellings for "sake cup"

Tags: word-choice, pronunciation, spelling, kanji-choice

When I was in Okinawa drinking sake I asked my host what the Japanese word for the sake cup was and was told:

> お猪口{ちょこ}

Then today I went to the [Nezu Museum](http://www.nezu-muse.or.jp/) in Tokyo which currently has a collection of sake utensils on display. Every single cup there bore the label:

> さかづき in the rubi and either 盃 or 酒盃 for the kanji.

So I was originally going to ask what the difference is between おちょこ and さかづき but on looking up the latter for the right kanji to use in this question I was bombarded with these variants:

> 杯(P); 盃; 坏; 巵; 卮; 盞; 觚; 觴; 酒盃(iK) 【さかずき(P); さかづき; うき(盞)】

So it seems that the exhibit was using neither the preferred/popular kanji nor the preferred/popular pronunciation!

What am I to make of all this? Which word should I use for sake cup? Why would the museum go with an uncommon variant? Are there nuances?

Comment: [ず and づ have merged in most dialects](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%95%E3%82%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB:Yotsugana.png).  They used to be distinguished, though.

Comment: @snailboat: Of course I knew this but forgot about it when doing this question \-:

Comment: Excuse me but what does "iK" stand for? (and... I don't understand 「are their nuances」part... )

Comment: @Chocolate: I don't know, I'm only copying and pasting what I find in WWWJDIC. I suppose it's something like "irregular kanji", "infrequent kanji", or "informal kanji".

Comment: ["iK word containing irregular kanji usage"](http://www.edrdg.org/jmdict/edict_doc.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think さかずき normally refers to something that looks like this: [image: さかずき] 
and can also be used as a general term for sake cup, including おちょこ:[image]
 I think さかづき is probably an archaic way of spelling it in hiragana(or katakana?). Nowadays we normally spell it as さかずき. As for 杯 and 盃... both look okay to me, though I think I learned it as 杯 at school... some people say 盃 is a 俗字(informal variant?) for 杯 but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2):

Well, to start off, お猪口 is the typical cup you see when sake is served hot.  It looks kind of like a ceramic shot glass, just with straighter sides and a little shorter.

さかずき are flatter and disc-like.  As for how to write it, my dictionary confirms the preferences listed in EDICT: 杯 is listed first, followed by 盃.  Unless I go to the 国語辞典 within the application, it leaves off the other two.  Given the fact that the latter is a 人名用 and the former is 常用, that would appear to indicate that 杯 is the way to go, however Wikipedia (and, in fact, the displays you've been reading) appear to prefer 盃.

Comment: At least a couple of the 盃 looked very much like the short stubby cylinder shaped お猪口 but still were labelled 盃. Photography wasn't allowed and I couldn't find pictures of the exhibition online unfortunately.

Comment: If 杯 is 常用 and 盃 is 人名用, wouldn't you want to go with the 常用 one, i.e. 杯?

Comment: @senshin: You're right.  I thought I'd put that in, but I guess my IME got confused from going back and forth so much.  Fixed.

Comment: Wikipedia is using 盃... http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%9B%83

Comment: Amended to reflect.

Comment: @Chocolate I think that might just be because [杯](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%9D%AF) is a disambiguation page for things like ～杯【はい】 because it has alternate meanings, while 盃 is unambiguous, so they picked 盃 for the article title.